# Storing data Using Linked List

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to write a c program that ask user some information about a brand and store it into linked list. But whenever user enters data it always overwrites the previous data, instead I wanted it to create new node and store it there. This is what I manage so far. How can I do it without using any temporary nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int count = 1;

struct modelNode{

    char name[50];
    int year;
    int amount;
    struct modelNode *next;
};

struct modelNode * addModel(struct modelNode *p);
void getBestModel(struct modelNode *p);

int main(){
    int command;

    struct modelNode * modelList = NULL;
    do
    {
        printf("1. Add a model\n");
        printf("2. Display the model with the highest selling amount\n");
        printf("3. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter command: ");
        scanf("%d", &command);
        switch(command)
        {
            case 1:
            addModel(modelList);
            printf("test %s\n", modelList->name);
            //printf("test %s\n", modelList->next->name);
            break;
            case 2:
            printf("45\n");
            break;
            case 3:
            puts("Bye");
            break;
            default:
            printf("default\n");
        }

    }while(command != 3);
    return 0;
}

struct modelNode * addModel(struct modelNode *p){
    int iter = 0;
    while(iter<count)
    {
        p = (struct modelNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct modelNode));
        p->next=NULL;
        iter++;




    }

    printf("test %s\n", p->name);


    printf("Enter the name: ");
    scanf("%s", &p->name);
    printf("Enter the release year: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->year);
    printf("Enter the selling amount: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->amount);
    p->next=NULL;

    printf("test %s\n", p->name);
    count++;


}

}
```

Comment: With `p = (struct modelNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct modelNode))` you throw away the pointer to the start of your linked list. You need to (with a loop) go to the end of your linked list. Then create a new node with malloc and add it to the end of the list by setting the next-filed of the last node in the list to the pointer to your new node

Answer (score 1):

The generic functions for adding a node to a linked list would be

```c
typedef struct node_t {
    struct node_t* next;
} node_t;

node_t* add(node_t* list, node_t* new_node) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        return new_node;
    } else {
        node_t* tmp = list;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        tmp->next = new_node;

        return list;
    }
}
```

and you could use it like

```c
node_t* list = NULL;

list = add(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
list = add(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
list = add(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
list = add(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));

// list would now be a list of 4 nodes
```

and if you really don't want to use a tmp variable to walk the list, you can do it like this

```c
void add_without_tmp(node_t* list, node_t* new_node) {
    if (list == NULL) {
        // some error handling
    } else {
        while(list->next != NULL) {
            list = list->next;
        }
        list->next = new_node;
    }
}

node_t* list = malloc(sizeof(node_t));

add_without_tmp(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
add_without_tmp(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));
add_without_tmp(list, malloc(sizeof(node_t)));

// list would now be a list of 4 nodes
```

**Edit:** fixed the error with the declaration of `node_t` and added the missing `*` to the statement `node_t* tmp = list;`.

Comment: Upvoted, this is a much better way. You should also address OP's *"How can i do it without using any temporary nodes."*

Comment: He could just insert "at head" and if he wants to insert at the tail he can go recursively through the linked list and add at the end. No temp nodes this way

Comment: I think you're trying to insert the new_node at the end, if you traverse the list that way, won't you lose the pointer to the head of list?

Comment: @Souza A copy of the original head pointer is passed to that function. How will the original list be modified this way?

Comment: @Souza you are right, your solution to insert at head is much better, but if the task is to add at the tail imho the loop is better as it will not requier any recursiv function calls which might pack onto the stack (depends on the optimization of the compiler)

Comment: @ArdentCoder that was not a comment about the loss of any pointer but on his comment before that, just bad luck with comment order

Comment: @Ackdari Haha, I see. Consider using the *Re: "point that you are replying to"* format in your comments to avoid such confusions, just a tip.

Comment: @Ackdari  `Spot on` my friend. I didn't use C for a long time to be honest. I think you're referring `node_t` inside the  struct without having it predefined. But again, i might be wrong .

Comment: @Souza you are right, fixed that and also found that there was a missing `*`.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a school exercise, so i doubt anyone here will solve it for you.
But you should try to insert "at the head" , you don't need temp nodes.

- Pass the **[head]** as a param of function addNodes:

Inside addNodes:

- Create **[new-node]**
- Set the "next" pointer from [new-node] to the [head]:
  **[new-node]->next = [head]**
- Return [new-node]

Resulting linked list (head is the old-head) :
**[new-node] ----> [head]**

If you do this twice you'll get this:
**[newer-node] -----> [new-node] ----> [head]**

And so on....

If you want to insert as "tail" , you just need to **traverse the linked list recursively**, this way you don't use temp nodes.

If i missed the point, please leave a comment explaining further.

If someone finds this, i added the solution in the comments after all:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node {
    int number;
    struct node* next;
} Node;

void addNode(Node * list, int n) {
    while(list->next) {
        list = list->next;
    }
    
    Node* new_node = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    new_node->next      = NULL;
    new_node->number    = n;
    list->next          = new_node;
}

void printLList(Node * *link){
    printf(" address inside (*link) %d , number inside head of link %d \n", (*link), (*link)->number);
    
    while((*link)){
        printf(" - %d - ", (*link)->number);
        *link = (*link)->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


void printLList2(Node * link){
    printf(" address inside link %d , number inside head of link %d \n", (link), link->number);
    while((link)){
        printf(" - %d - ", link->number);
        link = link->next;
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}


int main()
{

    Node* list = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    list->number = 42;
    list->next = NULL;

    addNode(list, 2);
    addNode(list, 3);
    addNode(list, 4);

    printLList2(list);
    printLList(&list);


}
```

Comment: But how can i travers  without using any temp node, i will lose my orginal list.

Comment: You don't lose it. I too forgot that C copies values by nature . Imagine this :
If you pass `changeVariable( a )`, you send a copy of `a`, if you instead do `changeVariable(&a)` , you are passing the address and you can change its value. So if you send  `addNode( list,  _ )` , you won't be able to change the original address inside variable `list` no matter what you do. You can do `list = list->next` .  You're safe.

Comment: So if I send a copy of my node through function it will be a whole new node ? But then if i do list = list->next with loop shouldn't it change the orginial one aswell ?

Comment: You need to remember that  `node` has only an address to a memory location, you don't have an actual "entire node" stored in that variable.  So let's say `node = 4242` , 4242 is only an address. If you use `addNode(node, _ )` you are sending a copy of `node`. If you try to change the copy you will not change the original `node` that is why you can do `node = (*node).next ` and if you do this, again, only changes the copy of `node`  . BUT , if you access the struct content using the 4242 address, you can change that content . Remember, it is only an address that lives inside `node`.

Comment: @Carl This will help you understand what we are discussing: https://onlinegdb.com/Sk-i8aVP8  . Check the address inside each version. Try to change the order of printLList and printLList2. One of them destroys the list. The other doesn't .